# ADF Jdeveloper Refresh Parent Form on Popup close

Tags: oracle-adf

I want to refresh(update few fields) on my parent form when OK button is clicked on Poup Dialog. But it does not refresh the fields. I have also set partialTriggers for the fields with Popup Id.
My Jdeveloper version is 11.1.1.7

Thanks

Umer Farooq

Answer (score 1):

All you need is linking the OK button action (or action listener) property with a call through an EL to a method provided on a managed bean. Then, in it you should refresh either each component or just the form/parent component keeping all of them(by registering it's bind into a partial target of the ADF context). The method should be similar to this example:

```
public String refresh() {

    AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(formToRefresh);

    return null;
}

private RichPanelFormLayout installDisable; //this should be the binding to the JSF form

public void setInstallDisable(RichPanelFormLayout installDisable) {
    this.installDisable = installDisable;
}

public RichPanelFormLayout getInstallDisable() {
    return installDisable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see what you implemented in your code in order to provide you the "best" solution overall - as theres multiple ways to implement a dialog in a popup. However, here's a couple options depending on how your Popup Dialog is programmed:

- **Dialog Listener** - use this if you use the built-in buttons of a dialog box. You'll need a managed bean for your jspx/jsf page. Create a Dialog Listener on your managed bean that is on your Dialog box. See below for a example of a dialog listener.

  ```
  public void myDialogListener(DialogEvent dialogEvent) {

   if (dialogEvent.getOutcome().equals(DialogEvent.Outcome.yes)) {
       // do something...
   } else if (dialogEvent.getOutcome().equals(DialogEvent.Outcome.no) {
       //do something...
   }
  }
  ```
- **Return Listener** - if you're running a task flow as a popup dialog, on your button, then add a ReturnListener to your page's managed bean. This fires whenever a your popup/dialog is closing.

  ```
  public void myReturnListener(ReturnEvent returnEvent) {
    //do something...
  }
  ```
- Otherwise, i'd add a an ActionListener to your manual button as Endrik suggests.

Now for refreshing your components, use this method in your managed bean, i use it all the time in my projects:

```
public void refreshComponent(UIComponent comp) {
    RequestContext rContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    rContext.addPartialTarget(comp);
}
```

To use it, you need to bind your Form's UI components to a managed bean. Then feed in the UI Component's bean property into the method.

For example, below will refresh a Rich Output Text that i have bound to a managed bean:
private RichOutputText myOutputText;

```
public void refreshMyStuff() {
    refreshComponent(myOutputText);
}
```

Have a good one.